# How to save a json file in azure webapp to use as environment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, webapi

I'm using the Google Credentials locally and I refer it by selecting the actual json file path "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" with WebApi, I couldn't find nothing to save the file so I just copied the whole information and put as a string inside of the Application settings on azure, but it didn't worked! How can I do this ?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your json file is in the project path, you can modify the csproj file to include your xxx.json file when publishing. Or manually add the json file in kudu. The path is as follows:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\xxx.json
```

Then set the environment variable in Application settings on portal as below:

[image]

Thanks for joey cai's answer, you can refer the origin post.

[Where to store the JSON file which will be referenced for the environment variable in asp.net hosted on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821909/where-to-store-the-json-file-which-will-be-referenced-for-the-environment-variab)